# Loop controls in JAVA. How to control i=1 to n.. button[i].setText() ? I dont want to as foreach

Tags: java, for-loop, button, jframe, controls

I am having 6 `label controls` in a java form (`JFrame`): `label1`, `label2` etc. till `label6`. How to 'refer' to the control in a loop like this:

```
for (i=1; i<=6; i++) 
{ 
    label[i].text = ...; //Some line of code here
}
```

Comment: So.. what are you asking? Does this code work? If not, what does it do that you don't expect?

Comment: It doesn't work on JAVA :( I need for loop controls..

Comment: String btnName;
        JButton butnesne = new JButton();
        for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
        {
            btnName = "jButton"+String.valueOf(i);
            btnName.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }

Comment: This code doesn't work on Java

Comment: "doesn't work on JAVA" is not a description of the problem. Does it compile? Does it throw an exception when you run it? Does it do something different to what you expect? etc etc. Help us to help you.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Can you give me facebook adress ? Can you help me on private

Comment: Nope, here is fine. Please just provide details of your problem in your question.

Comment: Can you put the labels in an array (even temporarily) so that the iteration over them works? Java is not a scripting language you can't just assemble variable names at runtime (or at least that isn't usually the correct way to code).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `JLabel` array and fill it with the loop :

```
JLabel[] labs = new JLabel[6];

for (int i = 0 ; i < labs.length ; i++){
    labs[i] = new JLabel("Whatever");
}
```

Comment: I dont want to create the object. Is it possible ?

Comment: @AliPinar what do you mean by create the object?

Comment: @AliPinar be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to getLabels which are inside in a Jframe.

//if you don't have contentpane use jframe.getComponents();

```
foreach(Component comp : jframe.getContentPane().getComponents()){
    System.out.println(comp.getLabel());
    comp.setLabel("Your Label");
}
```

Comment: It looks like the code is not formatted correctly.... Are the 2 lines above the code block meant to be included? "//if you don't have contentpane use jframe.getComponents();"

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP seems to want to name them `label1`, `label2`, `label3`, etc., this code will do that:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    label[i - 1].text = "label" + i;
}
```

Two things to notice:

`label[i - 1]`: Array numeration starts at zero. The first element is `array[0]`.

Second thing: `"label" + i`

This is an example of concatenation. I take the string `"label"` and I append `i` to the end of it. It is not numerical addition because I cannot add strings like numbers! Instead, the result is `"label?"`